# Groupboxes behaving as radiobuttons

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I know it is possible to have Radio Buttons (or any other item) in a GroupBox title, but the behavior of those is not linked.

Here is an image of my interface

[image]

Right now, the user can give confirmation either by clicking the "Create lesion" button, or clicking on an existing lesion in the list. I would like to let the user choose either one groupBox or the other, and disable the related information, so as to have a single confirmation button.

Comment: this might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263004/setting-radio-button-as-group-box-title), but I am specifically asking about QtQuickControls2 and the answers are 3 years old and only talk about QtQuickControls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`label`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-groupbox.html#label-prop) property to add the `RadioButton`, and `ButtonGroup`'s attached [`group`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-buttongroup.html#group-attached-prop) property to make the group boxes exclusive with each other:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ButtonGroup {
        id: checkGroup
    }

    RowLayout {
        GroupBox {
            id: newLesionGroupBox
            title: "New lesion"

            label: RowLayout {
                RadioButton {
                    id: newLesionRadioButton
                    checked: true

                    ButtonGroup.group: checkGroup
                }
                Label {
                    text: newLesionGroupBox.title
                    font: newLesionGroupBox.font
                }
            }

            Column {
                enabled: newLesionRadioButton.checked

                Label {
                    text: "Some stuff"
                }
                Button {
                    text: "Blah"
                }
            }
        }
        GroupBox {
            id: existingLesionGroupBox
            title: "Existing lesion"

            label: RowLayout {
                RadioButton {
                    id: existingLesionRadioButton

                    ButtonGroup.group: checkGroup
                }
                Label {
                    text: existingLesionGroupBox.title
                    font: existingLesionGroupBox.font
                }
            }

            Column {
                enabled: existingLesionRadioButton.checked

                Label {
                    text: "Some stuff"
                }
                Button {
                    text: "Blah"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can tidy this up a lot by making a reusable component out of the group box.

Each visual part of a control that can be customised has a link to the customisation docs, by the way. In this case, it links here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-groupbox

Comment: Nice, it works ! I had to pass the ButtonGroup as a property of my custom GroupBox, but it's working.